# Xbee Serial.read is not clearing buffer

Tags: arduino, xbee

I wrote a example program to test Serial read from xbee. I was expecting a message passed from transmitter to receiver every 5 sec's but in serial monitor of receiver I am observing a continuous stream of repeat messages. Can anyone what I am missing. FYI: Also attached link to serial monitor screenshot.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lgxx5.png

```
/*  ~ Simple Arduino - xBee Transmitter sketch ~ Router
*/

int count = 0;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    //Send the message:
    count ++;
    Serial.println(String("Hello World : " + String(count)));
  delay(5000);
}
```

```
/*  ~ Simple Arduino - xBee Receiver sketch ~ Coordinator
*/

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0){
    Serial.write(Serial.read());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a work around to address the issue. Here are the details:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qZMi.png

```
Circuit connections from Arduino to XBEE Shield: 
D0/RX to TX
D1/TX to RX 
5V to 5V 
GND to GND
```

```
/*  ~ Simple Arduino - xBee Transmitter sketch ~ Router
 */

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  //Send the message:
  Serial.print('<');
  Serial.print("Hello World");
  Serial.println('>');
  delay(1000);
}
```

```
/*  ~ Simple Arduino - xBee Receiver sketch ~ Coordinator
*/

bool started = false; //True: Message is strated
bool ended = false;   //True: Message is finished
byte index;           //Index of array

char character; //Variable to store the incoming byte
char msg[13];   //Message - array

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{

  while (Serial.available())
  {
    character = Serial.read();
    if (character == '<')
    {
      started = true;
      index = 0;
      msg[index] = '\0'; // Throw away any incomplete packet
    }

    //End the message when the '>' symbol is received
    else if (character == '>')
    {
      ended = true;
      break; // Done reading - exit from while loop!
    }

    //Read the message!
    else
    {
      if (index < 11)
      {                         // Make sure there is room
        msg[index] = character; // Add char to array
        index++;
        msg[index] = '\0'; // Add NULL to end
      }
    }
  }

  if (started && ended)
  {
    Serial.print("Message: ");
    Serial.println(msg);

    index = 0;
    msg[index] = '\0';
    started = false;
    ended = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the receiver, don't you just want to pass `Serial.read()` to `print()` instead of `Serial.write()`?  If you have two serial ports, one to the console and one to the XBee, they should have different names.

Could you provide some more details on your serial connections?  What are COM3 and COM6 attached to?  Are you sharing serial port pins with the XBee and your console?  it seems like that could be part of your problem, if either the Arduino or XBee can drive the RX pin of your receiver's serial port, you'd end up echoing your characters back to yourself.

Comment: Hi 

Thanks for reply.

I have connected both Ardunio's (transmitter and receiver) via USB to my PC. Transmitter is COM3. Receiver is COM6.

Here is circuit connections from Arduino to XBEE Shield:
D0/RX to TX
D1/TX to RX
5V to 5V
GND to GND

Comment: So that's the problem.  You're connecting the serial port to both the USB connection to your PC, and to the XBee module.

Comment: `Serial.println()` on the transmitter goes to the XBee AND to COM3 (that's why you see what you're sending).  And then your wiring on on the Receiver is such that you receive data from the XBee, but then echo it back out again, but in a way that might be looping the data back (maybe its `ATDH` and `ATDL` settings result in the data being sent to itself).  Find a way to have two serial ports (perhaps with "SoftwareSerial" for one) and connect one to the XBee and one to the USB connection to your PC.